# How to make file not open to public but javascript file under Wordpress folder can load it

Tags: permissions

I have one csv file for Wordpress using. It put under my theme folder. I don't want that open to public but only a js file under the theme folder can read it and retrive data.

How should I set the permission?

I have set the csv file permission to 640, it cannot open on the browser, but my js file cannot read it as well.

Comment: I don't think you can do that: you can't make it downloadable by a JS file but not the public. You could e.g. add some simple authentication or token e.g. as a header that the JS file adds when downloading the file, but the end user can just read that out of your script or just read the CSV out of the browser cache or network tab.

Comment: Your JS could make AJAX requests to a PHP endpoint instead, that performs lookups in the file (or a copy of the file loaded into the database?).